# How can I change the color of the current line marker in NetBeans 18?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, config

I want to change the color of the line that appears while I am typing to indicate where in the text I am (current line marker). I'm using NetBeans  18 and it currently has a dark color and I can't see it with the naked eye. What part of the configuration is that part of.

[Capture of how the current line marker is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPGfC.png)

I expected to find it in the part of Fonts & Color, but it was not like that.

Comment: Do either of the answers to [How to change the color of NetBeans cursor?](https://superuser.com/q/1368052) over on superuser help you?

Comment: I tried what it says, but it doesn't work for me either. :(

Comment: OK. I just tried [the answer posted by user Martí](https://superuser.com/a/1376250) and it didn't work for me either. But then I followed the advice in Martí's comment below their answer and it worked! Did you specifically try the suggestions in that comment? If you are still stuck I will post a step-by-step answer because changing the cursor color is definitely possible.